# Git Not Pushing nor Source Tree

Tags: git

As per comments:

I've been following bitbuckets instructions

**Already have a Git repository on your computer? Let's push it up to Bitbucket.**

```
cd /path/to/my/repo
git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:...
git push -u origin --all # pushes up the repo and its refs for the first time
git push origin --tags # pushes up any tags
```

I am getting this error message when trying to push through Atlassian Source Tree

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false push -v --tags --set-upstream origin master:master
Pushing to C:\...
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master[K
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare     repository[K
remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent[K

remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match[K
remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.[K
remote: error: [K
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to[K
remote: error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into[K
remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you[K
remote: error: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some[K
remote: error: other way.[K
remote: error: [K
remote: error: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set[K
remote: error: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.[K
To C:\...
! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)

error: failed to push some refs to 'C:\...'
```

Then I get this in the git terminal

```
No refs in common and none specified; doing nothing.
Perhaps you should specify a branch such as 'master'.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

I've added the SSH keys generated by SourceTree (puTTy) and from the terminal. Followed all the steps, yet I'm lost. I am brand new on this like 2 hours old HA. Can anyone step me in the correct location.

Comment: Can you include a better description of what you were doing leading up to the error message?

Comment: Updated, and that's basically what I've been doing

Comment: So can you pull and push from the command line, or is there even a problem there?

Comment: It appears you're trying to push to your local filesystem. Are you trying to push to an online remote like bit bucket or Github?

Comment: can't do either Tim and Jeff I'm trying to push my local files to an online remote

Answer (score 0):

Well, most probably you are trying to push to a local remote repository (sounds weird but nevertheless) — a repository located somewhere on your local hard drive. Look at that line `Pushing to C:\...`.

Also, the target repository is not a [bare repository](http://www.saintsjd.com/2011/01/what-is-a-bare-git-repository/), with the branch `master` being checked out. By default git refuses to push to an active branch of a remote non-bare repositories

Most likely, you intended to push to a "real remote repository". I'd suggest to check how the upstream repository is configured. To see this, try to invoke

```
 git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false config remote.origin.url
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In `SourceTree`, try changing `SSH Client` from `PuTTY/Plink` to `Open SSH`.